# Repeating SVG Pattern as a Clip Path for Border using ::after pseudo element

Tags: css, svg, mask, clip-path

I'm trying to create an asymmetrical sawtooth pattern at the bottom of a site header that looks like this (except the sawtooth would be asymmetrical):

[sawtooth border example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3kyo.png)

I've tried some pure CSS approaches using (linear-gradient) to no avail.

I can create a repeating pattern, but cannot also make it a clip-path such that it cuts out the background color  of the header (pink) to show the body background underneath.

https://codepen.io/rasterisk/pen/rZrKNO

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.header svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

div::after { /*this doesn't work*/
  content:'';
  height:12px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <svg width="3000" height="11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
      <clipPath id="svgPath">
        <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="12" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <path fill="" d="M-131-167l-144.42-104.93s-6.87-4.59-9.07 3.17c-2.11 7.48-13.93 83.86-16.69 101.76H-131zM-354-50l-.14 111s15.54-94.28 17.65-101.76c2.19-7.77 9.07-3.17 9.07-3.17L-183 61V-50h-171zM0 0v11.61S2.08 1.73 2.33.92C2.6.07 3.04.5 3.04.5L20 11.61V0H0z"/>
        </pattern>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" width="2400" height="12"/>
   </svg>
 </div>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated. This degree of SVG control is new terrain for me.

Comment: If you're going to use a pattern, you'd need a mask and a pattern cannot be the child of either a mask or a clipPath so the mask has a rect that is filled by a pattern.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for this information. I've been discovering a lot about the constraints with SVG Pattern and clipPath over the last 24 hours. I tried targeting pattern fills using CSS as well to no avail. I love what SVG is capable of but learning all the ins and outs is a serious study.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.header svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: tomato;//set your svg background color as your body color
}

div::after { /*this doesn't work*/
  content:'';
  height:12px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <svg width="3000" height="11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
      <clipPath id="svgPath">
        <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="12" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <path fill="" d="M-131-167l-144.42-104.93s-6.87-4.59-9.07 3.17c-2.11 7.48-13.93 83.86-16.69 101.76H-131zM-354-50l-.14 111s15.54-94.28 17.65-101.76c2.19-7.77 9.07-3.17 9.07-3.17L-183 61V-50h-171zM0 0v11.61S2.08 1.73 2.33.92C2.6.07 3.04.5 3.04.5L20 11.61V0H0z"/>
        </pattern>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" width="2400" height="12"/>
   </svg>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this css only solution: css linear gradients

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.header svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

div::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:1.2em;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, pink 25%, transparent 26%, transparent 75%, pink 75%),
      -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, pink 25%, tomato 26%,tomato 75%, pink 75%);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, pink 25%, transparent 26%, transparent 75%, pink 75%),
                  linear-gradient(135deg, pink 25%, tomato 26%, tomato 75%, pink 75%);
background-size:36px 36px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
 </div>
</body>
```

UPDATE

an asymmetrical sawtooth pattern:

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.header svg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

div::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,  tomato 50%, pink 50% , pink 100%),
                  linear-gradient(135deg,  tomato 50%, pink 50% , pink 100%);
background-size:25px 25px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The tricky part is that I needed the sawtooth effect to be asymmetrical. Appreciate the repsonse tho!